# Qt linguist doesn't translate the strings in ubuntu14.04

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, ubuntu-14.04

There is a simple code for translating. It runs in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextCodec>
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc,argv);
     QTranslator qtr;
     qtr.load("hello.qm");
     app.installTranslator(&qtr);
     //QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
     QLabel *label=new QLabel(QObject::tr("hello"));
     label->show();
     retrun app.exec();
}
```

I had followed the below steps to translate hello to the chinese 你好 by Qt linguist:

1. add `TRANSLATIONS +=hell0.ts` to hello.pro and lupdate.
2. open the Qt linguist and find that the interface is

[image: http://chuantu.biz/t/63/1422351082x-954498824.png]

It is not like the normal Qt linguist interface. This is my first problem. How can i fix it?

Then i print 你好 to translate 'hello', but nothing is displayed in the blank.
  I still push the 'done' button.

I use gedit to open the hello.ts and see that it has been tranlated to 你好.

The picture is

[image: http://chuantu.biz/t/63/1422354035x1822611189.png]

(3) I use 'lrelease' command and get the hello.qm

Last, i run the code as aboved. But the result is just to print 'hello' out.
It doesn't translate 'hello' to 你好. This is my second problem.

I also had used other methods like QtTextCodec::setCodecForTr instead of Qt linguist,but it still doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't translate the strings in ubuntu14.04" - so it works on Windows?

Comment: Where is the "hello.qm" file? You have hello. ts...

Comment: @sashoalm  it works on windows.

Comment: @UmNyobe I move the "hello.qm" to the directory "/home/weili/build-hello-desktop-Release" so that "hello.qm" and hello execute file are in the same directory. And I run the command "./hello" ,then nothing is displayed. But it will display after i remove the "hello.qm". I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `retranslateUI(this)` so the Translation will be updated